# Bad echo data from join table

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is my join table:

Model

```
public function blog_list()
{
    $this->db->select('b.id, bl.id_p, u.name, bl.cat2, b.vote');
    $this->db->join('blog b', 'bl.id_p = b.id_p');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'u.id = bl.id_p');
    $this->db->from('blog_list bl');

$this->db->get();
}
```

And my problem is that when I try echo all records from column for example id_p I get this records from blog table instead from blog_list. I try reverse blog with blog_lists and try different types of joining table, without expecting result.

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['blog_list'] = $this->users_m->blog_list();
    $where = "id_p = " . $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['user'] = $this->users_m->get('blog_list',$where,TRUE);
    $this->load->view('blog/blog_list', $data);
}
```

view:

```
    <?php foreach($blog_list as $row): ?>
          <?php echo ($row->name); ?> 
          <?php echo ($row->id); ?> 
          <?php echo ($row->id_p); ?> 
          <?php echo ($row->vote); ?> 
          <?php echo ($row->cat2); ?> 
          <?php echo anchor('blogs/blog/' . $row->id_p , 'Odwiedź >>'); ?> 
          <br><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
public function blog_list()
{
    $this->db->select('b.id_p, bl.id_p, u.name, bl.cat2, b.vote');
    $this->db->from('blog_list bl');
    $this->db->join('blog b', 'b.id_p = bl.id_p');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'u.id = bl.id_p');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

## UPDATE

```
public function blog_list()
{
    $this->db->select('b.id_p AS blog_id, 
                       bl.id_p AS blog_list_id, 
                       u.name AS user_name, 
                       bl.cat2 AS blog_list_cat, 
                       b.vote AS blog_vote');
    $this->db->from('blog_list bl');
    $this->db->join('blog b', 'b.id_p = bl.id_p');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'u.id = bl.id_p');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

And in code :

```
<?php foreach($blog_list as $row): ?>
      <?php echo ($row->user_name); ?> 
      <?php echo ($row->blog_id); ?> 
      <?php echo ($row->blog_list_id); ?> 
      <?php echo ($row->blog_vote); ?> 
      <?php echo ($row->blog_list_cat); ?> 
      <?php echo anchor('blogs/blog/' . $row->blog_list_id , 'Odwiedź >>'); ?> 
      <br><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Two errors:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 314

Error Number: 1052

Column 'id_p' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT `id_p`, `cat2` FROM (`blog_list` bl) JOIN `blog` b ON `bl`.`id_p` = `b`.`id_p` JOIN `users` u ON `u`.`id` = `bl`.`id_p`

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: @user3819713, I update my answer again, as I got to know, you are using codeigniter and the format should like above. You might have missed to add `b.id_p`, instead you added `b.id` previously.

Comment: I try that before, same result, echo records from blog table

Comment: I know wheres the problem, I've bad programming my database. I have to add id_b column to blog and connect id_b to id from blog_list. Lame mistake :< Sorry for your waste of time and I appreciate your help.